# I am navigating between pages in python using tkinter.however i can't get the functionality to work on some pages

Tags: python

Navigation works fine but some functionalities are not working. I really need this to work.I am trying to convert text to speech but i am getting some error.Thanks in advance 
I am getting the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Python27/gui_1.py", line 66, in printtext
    string = e.get()
NameError: global name 'e' is not defined
```

Here is the code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        e =tk.Entry(self)
        e.pack()
        e.focus_set()
        def printtext():
                global e
                string = e.get() 
                engine.say(string)  
                engine.runAndWait()


        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()
        b = tk.Button(self,text='okay',command=printtext)
        b.pack(side='bottom')



        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.pack()



app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the Global variable outside of the function printtext.

Comment: It worked bro.the error was due to some other thing this time.I fixed that.Thanks a lot.